# Difference between P2 and P2 Update site in Nexus P2 proxy support

Tags: java, nexus, p2

So I've installed nexus p2 plugin.

It gives me two options when creating a proxy on a P2 Repository. P2 and P2 Update Site.

What is the difference between the two and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: I think the p2 update site is deprecated..

Comment: why is this closed? does not seem opinion-based to me: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/42303763-P2-Repository-FAQ